# Microsoft.ReportView.ProcessingObjectModel Version 8.0.0.0 - Visual Studio 2005-2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, report-viewer2010

I have a program that was built in Visual Studio 2005.  However, this program does not run on Windows 7 machine.  I converted the project from Visual Studio 2005 to Visual Studio 2010.  I then copied the published files to a Windows 7 laptop and ran the executable from there.  When doing so,  I got the following error:

Unable to install or run the application.  The application requires that assembly Microsoft.ReportView.ProcessingObjectModel Version 8.0.0.0 be installed in the GAC first

Most of the solutions that I have found are for Visual Studio 8.  Anybody have an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by removing the Microsoft.ReportView.ProcessingObjectModel Version 8.0.0.0 from the assembly and adding 10.0.0.0 instead.